# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: not working correctly when testing on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

Currently i have a uitableview that the user can scroll through and select a cell. When the cell has been selected I save that indexpath value and when the user comes back to the view with the uitableview in it I pass that indexpath value back and assing a tick to that cell inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: using the code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//...


//Replaces previously selected cells accessory view (tick)
    if (indexPath == oldCheckedData) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@" Tick");
    } 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSLog(@"No Tick");
    } 
}
```

the weird thing being is that when testing this on the emulator it works perfectly.... However when I try to test it on the phone it never enters the first if statement... so the tick is never added.

Comment: You've been around long enough now that you should know how to format your own code. Please format code as `code`.

Comment: opps sorry just missed it. I just came back to the screen and saw it then when i reloaded I saw that you edited it for me.. thanks for that.. sorry about not formatting it.. I'm just so engrossed in this problem wasnt thinking straight :)

Comment: where do you set `oldCheckedData` ?

Comment: I think I need to double check that.. because I set it from another view with this method **- (void)setAccessoryIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myLastIndexPath
{
    oldCheckedData = [myLastIndexPath copy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}** but I also change its value in this view when another selection is made.

Comment: hmmm ... you compare the pointers of the NSIndexPath objects, and oldCheckedData is a COPY of the original NSIndexPath object - could it be that the way the simulator works with address references differs from the device? Maybe you should try to remember the index value itself instead of the whole indexpath.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part there.. what is the difference between an index value and the whole indexpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are comparing pointers, not the index path. Instead of equal equal, use:

```
[indexPath isEqual:oldCheckedData]
```

Comment: WORKED!!!!! bit pissed at myself however.. I should have spotted that I had some help yesterday in another area where I had to use isEqual.. but i just didnt see it... woop woop! thanks very much! :)